# Why Does Owl Carousel Break Bootstrap Modal In My Laravel App?

Tags: php, html, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

Good day. In my Laravel App, I have a foreach loop where I display all products. I also have a **quickview** modal where users can view the products without loading a new page. Furthermore, I am using `owlcarousel.js` to display the products. Unfortunately, owl.carousel breaks the bootstrap modal unless the modal is placed outside the owl.carousel. But, since the products are loaded on the page dynamically, I can't access the ids of the modals outside the owl carousel div which encompasses the loop.
The `$modal_id` variable is only returning the last Id in the loop. So, please what is the way out?
How can I access the individual ids within the loop from on click from outside

The code is shown below

```
<div class="product owl-carousel">
     <?php $modal_id = 0; ?>
    @foreach($new_arrivals as $new_arrival)

        <div class="pro">

                <div class="pro-img">
                    <?php $modal_id = $new_arrival->id?>

                    <span class="sticker-new">new</span>
                    <div class="quick-view-pro">

                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{$modal_id}}" class="quick-view modal-view"
                           href="#{{$modal_id}}" rel="{{$new_arrival->id}}"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>


    @endforeach

</div>


<!--   Modal is shown below    !-->

<div class="product-view">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="modal fade" id="{{$modal_id}}">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal footer -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need add your modal html in foreach.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. When I put the modal inside the foreach loop, owl carousel prevents it from showing. Maybe there's a conflict somewhere. That was why I decided to put it outside.

Comment: You can add second foreach for modal ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<div class="product owl-carousel">
     <?php $modal_id = 0; ?>
     <?php $modal_ids = []; ?>
    @foreach($new_arrivals as $new_arrival)

        <div class="pro">

                <div class="pro-img">
                    <?php $modal_id = $new_arrival->id?>
                    <?php $modal_ids[] = $new_arrival->id ?>

                    <span class="sticker-new">new</span>
                    <div class="quick-view-pro">

                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{$modal_id}}" class="quick-view modal-view"
                           href="#{{$modal_id}}" rel="{{$new_arrival->id}}"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>


    @endforeach

</div>


<!--   Modal is shown below    !-->

@foreach($modal_ids as $item)

    <div class="product-view">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="modal fade" id="{{$item}}">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
                    <div class="modal-content">

                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Modal body -->
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row">


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Modal footer -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Hope help you.

Comment: Thanks Sir. Will implement this.